# Hashable type with overwritten operators or external functors

Tags: c++, templates, functor, unordered-set

To use a custom type in a `std::unordered_set` I have to options.

1) Implement the `==` operator for my type and specialize `std::hash`

```
struct MyType {
    int x;

    bool operator==(const MyType& o) {
        return this.x == o.x;
    }
};

namespace std
{
template<>
struct hash<MyType> {
    size_t operator()(const MyType& o) const {
        return hash<int>()(o.x);
    }
};
}

std::unordered_set<MyType> mySet;
```

Or 2), provide functor classes:

```
struct MyTypeHash {
    size_t operator()(const MyType& o) const {
        return std::hash<int>()(o.x);
    }
};

struct MyTypeCompare {
  bool operator()(const MyType& o1, const MyType& o2) const {
    return o1.x == o2.x;
  }
};

std::unordered_set<MyType, MyTypeHash, MyTypeCompare> mySet;
```

The second approach lets me choose new behaviour for every new instantion of `std::unordered_set`, while with the first approach the behaviour as being part of the type itself will always be the same.

Now, if I know that I only ever want a single behaviour (I'll never define two different comparators for `MyType`), which approach is to be preferred? What other differences exist between those two?

Comment: I would say don't pollute std namespace unless default hash function is very good for the custom type. when you specialize `std::hash` struct you are basically providing a default if we don't take messing with namepace `std` into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching the behavior to the type allows for code like

```
template<template<class> Set,class T>
auto organizeWithSet(…);

/* elsewhere */ {
  organizeWithSet<std::unordered_set,MyType>(…);
  organizeWithSet<std::set,MyType>(…);
}
```

which obviously cannot pass custom function objects.

That said, it is possible to define

```
template<class T>
using MyUnorderedSet=std::unordered_set<T, MyTypeHash,MyTypeCompare>;
```

and use that as a template template argument, although that introduces yet another name and might be considered less readable.

Otherwise, you have to consider that your `operator==` is simultaneously the default for `std::unordered_set` and `std::find`, among others; if the equivalence you want for these purposes varies, you probably want named comparators.  On the other hand, if one suffices, C++20 might even let you define it merely with `=default`.